# Should I replace wet wood siding, or can I just paint it?

Tags: water, wood, siding, damage, rot

I had new wood siding installed on the front of my shed about 6 months ago,I haven't painted it or treated it yet. The bare wood has been exposed to the weather this entire time. It's T1-11 siding made of pine wood. It started to get wet at the bottom from rain, and it's got a dark color. I can't tell if it's mold, or if it's beginning to rot. Can I clean it and paint over it with primer + exterior paint? Or should the wet bottom portion of the siding be replaced altogether? It doesn't feel spongy or like it's flaking, but I'm concerned that it's too late for the wood to be recovered/protected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should clean and paint it, that will help (wait for it to dry first). However, with the siding in direct contact with the ground surface, the bottom edge is at higher risk for rotting regardless as it can soak up moisture easily. Depending what the surface it's on contact with changes the risk and how easily it can be mitigated.

Comment: Is the T-111 setting directly on the concrete slab? I think I see wall flashing under it, but the siding should have not been set tight to the flashing. The siding is still good for now, but in a few years because of this condition, it will start to rot.